# Always on Top function missing on FF, Chromium, Opera

Tags: gnome, 20.04, desktop-environments

Ubuntu 20.04 Buldgie using Arc Design desktop tweak. Tried super key right click, window not max on top & resize cursor. Always on top option does not show.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer to my problem. If I am in the resize window cursor and I hold the super key down while I click BOTH Left and Right mouse buttons simultaneously I get the menu with the "Always on top" option.